# Find a matching string in an array or a word in a string

Tags: php

I'm having difficult trying to create a function that would check to see if an item "the string" existed in database before i add it, if not then it will explode the string and find the matching string. this is what i did but missed it

UPDATE info: i have this problem where i compare the input value vs database value.

$database = "i'm;  $input ="im" when i compare the two using the function below it came out empty as in item not found. but when i try to reset the value of $input ="i'm" then ofcourse item found. And even with string_replace that basicly remove anything that is not letters or numbers on both values. i need help plz

```
//string_replace is to replace all spaces and special chars with "" 

public function match_string(){ 

  $name = $this->string_replace($this->name);

    $all_item = $this->find_all(); // find_all is to fetch all data from mysql table
    foreach($all_item as $item){ 

    $lowercase = $this->string_replace($item->name);
    if($lowercase == $name){ 
        // match found

    }elseif($item_explode=explode(" ",$item->name)){ 

        $name_explode = explode(" ",$this->name);
        foreach($name_explode as $key){ 

        if(in_array($key,$item_explode)){ 
        //match key found
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php to check if a word is in a string, use

```
if (strpos($word, $my_string) !== false)
{
    echo 'Word found';
}
```

Comment: i tried to use strpos but i keep getting error of empty delimiter

Answer (score -1):

`string_replace` is not a function in php.  You should be using the `str_replace` method, found here: https://www.php.net/str_replace

Comment: `string_replace` is a function created by the OP.

Comment: I guess `string_replace` is a method of OP's class.

Comment: the function string_replace is own function which created to remove all spaces and special chars.